# Creating XML code using image source from SlideshowPro Album using PHP

Tags: php, xml, slideshow

I used the code from this website http://wiki.slideshowpro.net/PlayerWithoutDirector/PWDSCRIPTS-PHPXMLBuilderScript with a copy of the code below called images.php with audio but I don't really need audio. This PHP script just retrieves the image source of photos in a directory of a folder to an XML file. Instead, I'd like to write an XML file that would get the image source directly from a SlideshowPro Album. The first code below lists the images from an album directly from SlideShowPro. How do I combine the two scripts?

```
// gallery.php
<?php

   include('classes/DirectorPHP.php');
   $director = new Director('api', 'key');

   $album = $director->album->get(440);
   echo $album->name . '<br /><br />';

   // Loop through album content
   $contents = $album->contents[0];
   foreach($contents as $content) {
      echo $content->src . '<br />';
   }
?>




// images.php 

<?php
/**************************************************************************

XML Generator for SlideShowPro
Brad Daily - slideshowpro.net

For instructions, see the wiki:
http://wiki.slideshowpro.net/SSPExtras/PhpXmlBuilder

This script is governed by the following license:
http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/us/

**************************************************************************/

/*
CONFIGURATION
*/

// Name of the folder in each album's folder that contains the full size imagery
$large_folder = 'lg';

// Name of the folder in each album's folder that contains the thumbnails
$thumb_folder = 'tn';

// Name of your album preview image. placed at the root of each album's folder (optional)      
$album_preview_name = 'albumPreview.jpg';

/* Audio addition 
$audio_folder = 'audio';
*/



/*
END CONFIGURATION
(DO NOT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE UNLESS YOU KNOW WHAT YOU ARE DOING)
*/

// Set up paths
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
$dir = dirname(__FILE__);
$server = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$rel_path = str_replace('images.php', '', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$path = $server . $rel_path;
$iptc = is_callable('iptcparse');
/*$width = "thumbnailWidth=auto thumbnailHeight=78";  */


// Find all folders in this directory
$albums = array();

$d = dir($dir);
while (false !== ($folder = $d->read())) {
if ($folder != '.' && $folder != '..' && is_dir($dir . DS . $folder . DS . $large_folder))   
{
$albums[] = $folder;
}
}
$d->close();
// Start writing XML
$o = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' . "\n<galleries>\n";

// Cycle through albums
foreach($albums as $album) {
// Path variables
$loc_path = $path . $album . '/';
$full_path = $dir . DS . $album;

// Find images in the large folder
$images = array();
$d2 = dir($full_path . DS . $large_folder);
while (false !== ($image = $d2->read())) {
if (eregi('.jpg|.gif|.png|.swf|.flv|.mov', $image)) {
$images[] = $image;
 }
}
$d2->close();

/* Audio addition 
// Find audios in the audio folder
$audios = array();
$d2 = dir($full_path . DS . $audio_folder);
while (false !== ($audio = $d2->read())) {
if (eregi('.mp3|.ra|.wav', $audio)) {
$audios[] = $audio;
}
} 
$d2->close();
Audio addition */


// Only write the album to XML if there are images
if (!empty($images)) {
natcasesort($images);
// Pretty up the title
$title = ucwords(preg_replace('/_|-/', ' ', $album));

// See if there is an album thumb present, if so add it in
if (file_exists($full_path . DS . $album_preview_name)) {
$atn = ' tn="' . $loc_path . $album_preview_name . '"';
} else {
$atn = '';
}

// Only write tnPath if that folder exists
if (is_dir($full_path . DS . $thumb_folder)) {
$tn = ' tnPath="' . $loc_path . $thumb_folder . '/"';
}
/* Audio addition 
$audio = '';
if (0 < count($audios)) {
    $audio = sprintf(' audio="%s" audioCaption="%s"',
                     $loc_path . $audio_folder . '/' . $audios[0],
                     substr(ucwords(preg_replace('/_|-/', ' ', $audios[0])), 0, -4));
 }
 Audio addition */

// Album tag
$o .= "\t" . '<imagegroup title="' . $title . '" thumbnailPath="' . $loc_path .  
$large_folder . '/"' . $width . $atn . $audio . '>' . "\n";

// Cycle through images, adding tag for each to XML
foreach($images as $i) {
$link = $caption = '';
$title = '';

if ($iptc) {
$file = $full_path . DS . $large_folder . DS . $i;
$path_info = pathinfo($file);
$extensions = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png');
if (in_array(strtolower($path_info['extension']), $extensions)) {
getimagesize($file, $info);
if (!empty($info['APP13'])) {
$iptc = iptcparse($info['APP13']);
if (isset($iptc['2#005'])) {
$title = $iptc['2#005'];
if (is_array($title)) {
$title = htmlentities($title[0], ENT_COMPAT);
}
}
if (isset($iptc['2#120'])) {
$caption = $iptc['2#120'];
if (is_array($caption)) {
$caption = htmlentities($caption[0], ENT_COMPAT);
}
}
}
}
}

if (isset($_GET['link'])) { $link = $loc_path . $large_folder . '/' . $i; }
$o .= "\t\t" . '<img src="' . $i . '" title="' . $title . '" />' . "\n";
}

// Close the album tag
$o .= "\t</imagegroup>\n";
}
}

// Close gallery tag, set header and output XML
$o .= "</galleries>";
header('Content-type: text/xml');
die($o);
```

I'd like my result to appear like this:

```
<galleries>

<imagegroup title="2013 In Review" thumbnailPath="2013Review/thumb.jpg" thumbnailWidth="auto" thumbnailHeight="78">
<img src="2013Review/JLP09509_01_026.jpg" title="Paul Walker by Jeff Lipsky"/>
<img src="2013Review/NAB10003_01_001.jpg" title="Nelson Mandela by Nabil"/>
<img src="2013Review/MMU13110_41_001.jpg" title="Lindsey Vonn by Michael Muller"/>
</imagegroup>

<imagegroup title="Awards Season" thumbnailPath="AwardSeason/thumb.jpg" thumbnailWidth="56" thumbnailHeight="78">
<img src="AwardSeason/GBE07090_04_007.jpg" title="Tom Hanks by Giuliano Bekor - &quot;Captain Phillips&quot;"/>
<img src="AwardSeason/DTI12009_02_001.jpg" title="Amy Adams by Darren Tieste - &quot;American Hustle&quot; "/>
<img src="AwardSeason/NPA11013_01_005.jpg" title="Idris Elba by Nigel Parry - &quot;Mandela-Long Walk to Freedom&quot; "/>
</imagegroup>

</galleries>
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: I posted the code and edited my question. I hope this clarifies it. Thanks.